# Image and Text locations in UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiedgeinsets

Im trying to put a `UIImage` and text into a `UIButton`, by using `UIEdgeInset` to locate them.

The problem is, changing one of the edgeinset setting will cause both the image and the text to change the position.
Which means, I put the image to the correct position, then I change the `titleEdgeInset` values, suddenly not only the text but also the image changed the position.

Any one can help out please?

Comment: Please ellaborate a little more, share some code as to where and how are you changing the insets and, what is happening to the position

Comment: You can try create a new Custom button class and implement UIButton, override UIButton by adding the labels and image on the custom button as its property, import the class and then initialise it on your view to use it. The init statement will look like -> CustomButton*custBtn = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

Answer (score 0):

According the Apple's documentation this won't happen. Did you check to make sure you have negative insets and not positive?

> The insets you specify are applied to the title rectangle after that rectangle has been sized to fit the button’s text. Thus, positive inset values may actually clip the title text.
>
> This property is used only for positioning the title during layout.
>   The button does not use this property to determine
>   intrinsicContentSize and sizeThatFits:.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may helps you

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Imagetext;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click  Me"];

NSTextAttachment *ImageAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
ImageAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];

NSAttributedString *attributedWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:ImageAttachment];

[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(6, 0) withAttributedString:attributedWithImage];
//    [attributedString appendAttributedString:attributedWithImage];

[self.Imagetext setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```